# Plot a map and add points via loop without reloading map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a world map and add some points to the map, without reloading the map and just remove the previous point and add a new point.
I tried with this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Data)){
     print(ggplot2::ggplot(Data) +
          ggplot2::ggtitle("World Map with Earthquake-data") +
          ggplot2::geom_polygon(data = ggplot2::map_data("world"),
                                fill = "lightgreen",
                                colour = "black",
                                ggplot2::aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
          ggplot2::theme(panel.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill = "lightblue"),
                         panel.grid.major = ggplot2::element_line(colour = "black"),
                         panel.grid.minor = ggplot2::element_blank()) +
          ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(name = "lon", limits = c(-180, 180),
                                      breaks = seq(-180, 180, 10)) +
          ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(name = "lat", limits = c(-90, 90),
                                      breaks = seq(-90, 90, 10)) +
          ggplot2::geom_point(data = Data[i, ],
                              ggplot2::aes(x=lon, y=lat, color = "red", size = mw)) +
          ggplot2::coord_fixed())
    Sys.sleep(3)
}
```

and similar ways. The problem is: its works fine, but always reloads the world map, obviously. I didnt figure out how to realize it with a loop inside the ggplot object to only loop through the earthquake data and remove the previous and add the next earthquake.
The data contains ~40k rows and 5 columns. These are the first 10 rows:

column titles: date;lat;lon;depth;mag

```
1904-04-04;41.758;23.249;15;7.02
1904-06-25;51.424;161.638;15;7.50
1904-06-25;52.763;160.277;30;7.70
1904-12-20;8.962;-84.042;10;7.29
1905-02-14;51.890;-176.702;35;7.59
1905-02-17;23.689;97.170;15;7.26
1905-02-19;-14.123;169.457;15;7.33
1905-03-04;-6.639;151.225;15;6.96
1905-03-04;-4.635;149.105;15;7.01
1905-03-22;51.145;-179.859;35;7.18
```

A nice additional feature would be to go through all days and not just skip from row to row. Some "empty" days and not only the days some earthquake happened.
Thanks for your answers.

Kind regards and stay healthy
Chamflo

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to make an animation? Have you tried the `gganimate` package? If you want individual plots, you can break the plot creation at any `+` point and assign that to a variable, and then use `+` on the variable to add more things to the plot. So move all the fixed parts of the plot (map, aesthetics, scales, ...) outside the loop and assign it to a variable. Then inside the loop add the non-fixed parts (points) to the variable (without saving it to the variable).

Comment: @cymon Thanks for your quick reply.
Yes, in the end it should be a "movie" or animation from the first to the last date. The gganimate package skipped many rows and only rendered 100 images. It should be ~40k like my rows am i wrong?

The idea of only adding the points via for loop and outsource the map as a variable loads forever. How do i not save it to the varibale? maybe thats what i did wrong

Comment: gganimate has parameters to control the number of frames, duration of frame, frames per second... But 40k frames might be outside its capabilities, I don't know it well. Ggplot evaluates some of its layers only on printing not on creation. If that's happening with the map, you can't get around it. Maybe save the map separately as a static image that you then use as plot background, theme() should allow something like that.